# What does the Value in PHP Composer's key/value Pair Represent?

Tags: php, composer-php

In a PHP `composer.json` file, the `require` field contains a number of key/value pairs.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/console": "~2.3@dev",
    "symfony/finder": "2.2.1",
    "symfony/yaml": "2.2.1",
    "symfony/process": "2.2.1",
    "symfony/validator": "2.2.1",
    "n98/junit-xml": "dev-master",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "1.1.0",
    "composer/composer": "dev-master"
},
```

What, exactly, is the value of each key/value pair used for?

I get that conceptually these are just version numbers.  For example, the following

```
"symfony/finder": "2.2.1"
```

tells composer that version `2.2.1` of the `symfony/finder` package is required.

What I'm unclear on is

1. The syntax allowed for versioning (i.e. what does `~2.3@dev` mean)
2. Why some versions are just text (`dev-master`)

My assumption is these somehow related to branches or tags in a version control system, or maybe the explicit version defined in a package's `composer.json` file, but I haven't been able to glean how, exactly, this works.

If anyone knows, or can point me to the right section of [the manual](http://getcomposer.org/doc/) where this is explained, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The ~2.3@dev means: "using ~ specifies a minimum version, but allows the last digit specified to go up." and dev means its a dev version, "Available options (in order of stability) are dev, alpha, beta, RC, and stable."
2. it means its a master branch

All of this i found it here:

- http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions
- http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability
- http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md
- http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev

Comment: +1 for good information — but what's a master branch?  i.e. Is that version control system branch, or something defined in composer?  Is it just a named branch or do "dev" and "master" have special meanings in composer. And what's a branch name doing where a version number should be? How does a master branch get sorted in the version compares?  (It seems like each manual section does a good job of explaining one aspect of all this, but there's nothing that ties it all together)

Comment: Yes is the version control branch, Composer min. requirements says: "To install packages from sources instead of simple zip archives, you will need git, svn or hg depending on how the package is version-controlled."
Using the word "dev-master" means that its the master branch, its just an alias to a specific version but that may change in the moment that you install it or update it. This also can lead to problems like the one described here:https://igor.io/2013/01/07/composer-versioning.html